# Is it possible to split a HTML textarea?

Tags: javascript, html, jsp, textarea

In my chat application I need to split a single textarea in to two parts and have to use it for dual purpose.

One to display the messages and another one to display the current time with every messages.

Is it possible ? Please correct me if I asked a wrong approach .

My need is to display the messages in the left side of the textarea and time in the right side of the test area.

or give some ideas to implement...

Comment: Do you mean a textarea as in a `<textarea>`? Why would you display messages in textareas? Don't you only need that for input?

Comment: Why is using two text areas - side by side - not good?

Comment: No text area is to display the messages from the agent side and also from the customer side messages.I am doing customer side chat application.

Comment: @ppeterka, why is using textarea for static data like date is good... :)

Comment: @gdoron You're right, but he wants textarea - he gets textarea suggestion...

Comment: @ppeterka My need is to display the messages in the left side of the textarea and time in the right side of the text area. If it can be done in single textarea means I welcome.

Comment: @Anand, why won't you get the answer: **DON'T DO THAT!!!**

Comment: `textarea` elements are for getting data from clients, not outputting data to them. Use a `<table>`. Each row consists of the metadata about a message and the message itself.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want.?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.time
{
position:absolute;
left:400px;
top:20px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<textarea rows="4" cols="50">
your chat messages
</textarea>
<div class="time">
4.30
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @Anand: k cool... if am right,your contents are dynamic. with rough css better go for a text area and a div or else  javascript would be the perfect choice.